# What Manufacturing Process Is Needed To Stretch Vinyl Material Around A Cushion With Complex Curves While Not Creasing The Vinyl?

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering

What manufacturing process is needed to stretch vinyl material around a cushion with complex curves, while not creasing the vinyl?  The accompanying image exhibits a cushion that is a result of the aforementioned process.  The pictured cushion is comprised of a three-quarter inch thick plywood base, onto which is placed a foam layer that is approximately three inches thick.  The plywood and foam are then all covered by what appears to be a four-way stretch vinyl material, such that the vinyl material exhibits no creases or wrinkles.  It is as if the covering material is heat-shrunk around the plywood and foam, while preserving the geometry of the foam layer.
[image]

Comment: Vacuum thermo-forming. $$$

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybPGPSsKu4I